# SYMFONY FORM NULL on SUBMIT when embedded with conditional in a loop (and table) inside TWIG template

Tags: forms, symfony-forms, symfony

I had trouble with a **SYMFONY FORM**, it was providing **NULL on SUBMIT**.

After some research, I've found a **workaround: I could get accurate value submitted with my form if I'd move the TWIG html code to render the form outside a table** (Because the form I want to render should appear on an extended row of a table).

Here is what I had (case 1):

```
{% if list is defined %}
    {% set table_root_id = pageName ~ '_table' %}
        <div class='col-12'>
            <table  data-role='table' id='{{table_root_id}}_id' data-mode='reflow' class='table-reflow-breakpoint table-stripe col-12'>
            <thead class='col-12'>
                <tr class='col-12'>
                  <th class='col-2'>{{'MyBundle.id'|trans}}</th>
                  <th class='col-4'>{{'MyBundle.lastname'|trans}}</th>
                  <th class='col-4'>{{'MyBundle.firstname'|trans}}</th>
                  <th class='col-2'>{{'MyBundle.action'|trans}}</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class='col-12'>
            {% for entity in list %}
                {% set row_root_id = table_root_id ~ '_row_for_' ~ entity.id %}
                <tr id = '{{row_root_id}}_id'  class='col-12'>
                    <th class='col-2' >{{ entity.id }}</th>
                    <td class='col-4'>{{ entity.lastname }}</td>
                    <td class='col-4'>{{ entity.firstname }}</td>
                    <td class='col-2'>
                        <span class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-user" title='{{"MyBundle.edit_user_profile"|trans}}' onclick='(new TableTupleButton("{{ table_root_id }}")).click({"route": "my_route", "page": "{{ pageName }}","post":{"entity_id_to_extend":"{{ entity.id }}}})'>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    {% if app.request.session.get('entity_id_to_extend') ==  entity.id %}
                     {% set idOfContainerToInsertBelowTuple = 'container_of_'~ app.request.session.get('entity_id_to_extend') %}
                     <div  class='col-12' id='{{ idOfContainerToInsertBelowTuple }}'>
                          {{ form(form_row_expanded) }}
                      </div>
                      <script type="text/javascript">
                         $(document).ready(new TableTupleButton('{{ table_root_id }}').extendRow('{{ idOfContainerToInsertBelowTuple }}','{{row_root_id}}'));
                      </script>
                    {% endif %}
                </tr>    
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

What I had above did not work, and also  {{ form(form_row_expanded) }} was rendered correctly, on a submit of that form, the value inside it were lost.

After few hours trying to spot the issue I found the following workaround (case 2):

```
 {% set idOfContainerToInsertBelowTuple = 'container_of_'~ app.request.session.get('entity_id_to_extend') %}
 <div  class='col-12' id='{{ idOfContainerToInsertBelowTuple }}'>
      {{ form(form_row_expanded) }}
 </div>

 {% if list is defined %}
        {% set table_root_id = pageName ~ '_table' %}
            <div class='col-12'>
                <table  data-role='table' id='{{table_root_id}}_id' data-mode='reflow' class='table-reflow-breakpoint table-stripe col-12'>
                <thead class='col-12'>
                    <tr class='col-12'>
                      <th class='col-2'>{{'MyBundle.id'|trans}}</th>
                      <th class='col-4'>{{'MyBundle.lastname'|trans}}</th>
                      <th class='col-4'>{{'MyBundle.firstname'|trans}}</th>
                      <th class='col-2'>{{'MyBundle.action'|trans}}</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class='col-12'>
                {% for entity in list %}
                    {% set row_root_id = table_root_id ~ '_row_for_' ~ entity.id %}
                    <tr id = '{{row_root_id}}_id'  class='col-12'>
                        <th class='col-2' >{{ entity.id }}</th>
                        <td class='col-4'>{{ entity.lastname }}</td>
                        <td class='col-4'>{{ entity.firstname }}</td>
                        <td class='col-2'>
                            <span class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-user" title='{{"MyBundle.edit_user_profile"|trans}}' onclick='(new TableTupleButton("{{ table_root_id }}")).click({"route": "my_route", "page": "{{ pageName }}","post":{"entity_id_to_extend":"{{ entity.id }}}})'>
                            </span>
                        </td>
                        {% if app.request.session.get('entity_id_to_extend') ==  entity.id %}

                          <script type="text/javascript">
                             $(document).ready(new TableTupleButton('{{ table_root_id }}').extendRow('{{ idOfContainerToInsertBelowTuple }}','{{row_root_id}}'));
                          </script>
                        {% endif %}
                    </tr>    
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

**One notice I had to take {{ form(form_row_expanded) }} outside the loop thru "entity" so as to have the SUBMIT working properly and submitting the values.**

I don't understand why it did not work in case 1? Could anyone give me some insight?

**NB**:

- new TableTupleButton("{{ table_root_id }}")).click(...) is a JS
  function to expand the row with the form (refresh the page telling
  which row should be expanded);
- new TableTupleButton('{{ table_root_id }}').extendRow(...)) is a JS
  function to place an expanded row under the correct row under which
  it should fit;